# R: Heatmaply creates empty/ white space in viewer

Tags: r, heatmaply

i tried to create a heatmap with my own data and kept only getting white space. I found [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html) very basic instruction on how to work heatmaply based on the mtcars data. After restarting R (close Window and reopen, not build-in restart) I tried and still only received white space. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
library(heatmaply)
mtcars <- get(data('mtcars'))
heatmaply(mtcars)
```

Comment: I didn't have any issue producing the map using R-3.6.3. What R version you are using? You can find the info using ```sessionInfo()``` if needed.

Comment: That's what I thought :s I am using R version 3.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonud it. Apparently it doesn't show up in the small "Viewer" Tab, but is opened once I click the "Show in new window" icon under the Tabs..

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this page. There are examples, including mtcars. There is a lot of explanation.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html

KR

Comment: Hi, 
thanks, I've already looked at this page. Sadly it doesn't mention the phenomenon of nothing.